# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() return null

Tags: java, android, file, nullpointerexception, null

I m trying to get the Internal Storage path of a Android Device.

Since most of the devices late off return Internal Storage path using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();` so I am using this to get the path.

Every thing is working fine except that when I am calling `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();` from an non Activity class it is returning null whereas if I call it from a Activity class it returns the correct path.

I Tried searching other posts but could not find anything useful.

Any help would be really grateful.

**EDIT:**

```
if(getExtSdCardPath(con)!=null)
    {  path=getExtSdCardPath(con);

        if(new File(path).getPath().equal(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath())) // This line give null "Null Pointer exception"
        {
            return  null;
        }
        return path;
    }
```

I am checking if the SD Card path is same as the path which is returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()`

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` does not involve a `Context`, and so its results should not change based on where the call is made. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and how you have determined that it is returning `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added some extra Information. Can you please have a look.

Comment: I think that it is more likely that `path` is `null`, so that `new File(path).getPath()` is `null`. BTW, `new File(path).getPath()` is pointless -- it would be faster to replace that with just `path`. And, also note that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` has little to do with "ext sd card" on most Android devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am checking if the value that has been assigned to `path` is not null `getExtSdCardPath(con)!=null` before calling the next code. And then I am assigning the value to path.  So I feel the only reason that is causing the error is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()`. Thank you for suggestion would replace `new File(path).getPath()` with `path` only.

Comment: "I am checking if the value..." -- you are assuming that two successive calls to whatever `getExtSdCardPath()` is will return the same value. In your current implementation, if the second call returns `null`, then `path` will be `null`, and you will get a `NullPointerException` on the indicated line. Only call `getExtSdCardPath()` once, and check `path` itself to see if it is `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank You very much. That actually solved my problem. Can you Please answer the question so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, `getExtSdCardPath()` would be "idempotent", which is a fancy way of saying "does the same work and returns the same thing no matter how many times you call it".

In your case, it is not. The first call to `getExtSdCardPath()` is returning the value that you want, and the second call to `getExtSdCardPath()` is returning `null`.

In your case, there is no particular need to call `getExtSdCardPath()` twice, and so you can work around the idempotence issue by rewriting your code to be something like:

```
path=getExtSdCardPath(con);
if(path!=null)
    {  
        if(new File(path).getPath().equal(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath())) // This line give null "Null Pointer exception"
        {
            return  null;
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you once again for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you forgot to put the requested permission in the manifest OR/AND forgot to ask for such a permission in runtime (in case you run this on devices with android 6.0 and above).

try to addto your manifest : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Here a quick and simple implementation example of how to request the permission in runtime:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 111; //Number is not matter, just put what you want

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Do your stuff with the file
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        requestPermission();
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            //Do your stuff with the file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as said in the question it is working fine in an Activity class and also I have added the permission and also I am taking runtime permission for 6.0+.